# Passing and receiving data between a php and .exe application.

Tags: php, .net, vb.net

there is a complex situation wherein, I have to pass a string data to a .exe application and this .exe application would process the string and respond back to my php data.
Any leads on how can this be done? I prefer not to use a TCP/IP connection.
Please suggest something.

Comment: Sounds like something you might want to do with a webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be performed using 'proc_open'.
Popen executes a command and then lets you send data to it and read data from it using regular i/o commands.
Look at [the php manual describing proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) for details and examples that tell it all.

So what you need to do:

- create a commandline
- feed that to proc_open
- read the output of the exe

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I could figure it out today! :)